# Spring boot and i18n, not using correct language

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I use spring boot 2, thymeleaf and spring security.

In spring boot, the locale seem  to be took from the browser language. Surely sent via Accept-Language
Is it possible to override that? Maybe is not neccessary...

What i try to do is to take lang value from user (**CustomUserDetail**) and use this value to use this value to display correct value from my thymeleaf page.

I created a class who implements **AuthenticationSuccessHandler**, it take lang value from user .

I do

```
LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(StringUtils.parseLocaleString(user.getLang()));
```

My browser local is in english, my user lang is french.

After user connect successfuly, web page continue to be displayed in **english**.

In my application.properties, I have

> spring.messages.fallback-to-system-locale=false

Comment: And why should it? You are only setting the locale after the login. You should reset it for each request. You want to use the language of the user so create a `LocaleResolver` which uses the `User` to set the `Locale` instead of the default resolver.

Comment: like i done, the page should be displayed in french... not in english

Comment: Read my comment... What you have done won't work.